# Not able to save selected value from a UIPickerView to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uipickerview

So far I have tried to use

```
func pickerView1(_ helpTypePicker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int { 
  infoListInit.requestInfoList[4] = (helpTypePickerValues[row]) 
}
```

But the value is just not saving to the array. I tried printing the value after saving it, but to no avail. I do have helpTypePicker as a self delegate in my viewDidLoad func, so I don't know where to go from here. Other text values from UITextFields save fine, but none of my UIPickerViews are working in this regard

Here is the full class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class requestHelpTypePickerScreen: UIViewController, 
UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent 
 component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return helpTypePickerValues.count
    } else {
        return languagePickerValues.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return "\(helpTypePickerValues[row])"
    } else {
        return "\(languagePickerValues[row])"
    }
}
// Mark: outlets
@IBOutlet weak var helpTypePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var languagePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var helpTypePickerLabel: UILabel!

let helpTypePickerValues = ["Academic/Professional", "Donate", "Food/Groceries", "Medication", "Emotional Support", "Misc."]
let languagePickerValues = ["Arabic", "Chinese", "Spanish", "English", "French", "Hindi/Urdu", "Korean", "Russian"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    helpTypePicker.delegate = self
    languagePicker.delegate = self
    self.helpTypePicker.selectRow(2, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    self.languagePicker.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}

// Mark: actions
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    func pickerView(_ helpTypePicker: UIPickerView,
    didSelectRow row: Int,
    inComponent component: Int) {
        infoListInit.requestInfoList[5] = (helpTypePickerValues[row])
    }
    
    // this is called pickerView1 because it would conflict with the above 
    // function if called pickerView
    func pickerView1(_ languagePicker: UIPickerView,
    didSelectRow row1: Int,
    inComponent component: Int) {
        infoListInit.requestInfoList[6] = (languagePickerValues[row1])
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "pickersDone", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Does the function itself get called? Or it just doesn't get saved to the array?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the function name it says `pickerView1` instead of `pickerView` (without the 1)

Comment: Please check if delegate is assigned or not. put related code to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code, the Delegate indicates that when a new row is selected in the `UIPickerView`, the function `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` will be called (the argument name doesn't matter).

In your case in when any of the pickers select a new row `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` is called with the picker passed as arguments in the firs position. You should check which picker was modified and then change your logic.

In your case:

```swift
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == helpTypePicker {
        infoListInit.requestInfoList[5] = helpTypePickerValues[row]
    } else {
        infoListInit.requestInfoList[6] = languagePickerValues[row]
    }
}
```